# NSKeyedArchiver unarchiveObjectWithData returning object with nil values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

**UserBean .h file**

```
@property (assign, readwrite) NSString *user;
@property (assign, readwrite) NSString *timestamp;
@property (assign, readwrite) NSString *password;
@property (assign, readwrite) NSString *source_id;
@property (assign, readwrite) NSString *fullname;
@property (assign, readwrite) NSString *email;
@property (assign, readwrite) NSString *reset_code;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;
```

**UserBean .m File**

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
    [encoder encodeObject:self.email forKey:@"email"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.user forKey:@"username"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.fullname forKey:@"fullname"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.password forKey:@"password"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.source_id forKey:@"id"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.timestamp forKey:@"timestamp"];
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        //decode properties, other class vars
        self.email = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"email"];
        self.user = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"username"];
        self.fullname = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"fullname"];
        self.password = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"password"];
        self.source_id = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"id"];
        self.timestamp = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"timestamp"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here i am saving and getting back userbean class object

```
- (UserBean *)getUser                       {
    NSError *error;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *encodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"user"];
    if (@available(iOS 9.0, *)) {
        UserBean *userBean = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData:encodedObject error:&error];
        return userBean;
    } else {
        UserBean *userBean = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
        return userBean;
    }
}
- (void)saveUser:(UserBean *)userBean       {
    NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:userBean];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:encodedObject forKey:@"user"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

from here i am setting object attributes and saving

```
- (void)saveUser:(StandardPacket *)packet               {
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [packet.data objectAtIndex:0];
    UserBean *userBean = [[UserBean alloc] init];

    userBean.user = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"username"]];
    userBean.email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"email"]];
    userBean.fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"fullname"]];
    userBean.password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"password"]];
    userBean.source_id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"id"]];

    userBean.timestamp = @"AA";
    userBean.reset_code = @"AA";

    [[SharedPrefences defaults] saveUser:userBean];
}
```

but when i retrieve object from SharedPreferences i am getting object with nil values and other garbage

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xa17e4c52)

values from userbean object after retrieving

user    UserBean *  0x17e604e0
_user   NSString *  0x17ea9fe0

_timestamp  NSString *  0x17ea7a50

_password   NSString *  0x17e605c0

_source_id  NSString *  0x17e679d0

_fullname   NSString *  0x17ea9e50

_email  NSString *  0x17e9a880

_reset_code NSString *  nil 0x00000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to encode the in encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder function.

```
[encoder encodeObject:self.reset_code forKey:@"reset_code"];
```

Also, add in initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder function.

```
 self.reset_code = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"reset_code"];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you but i figured it out issue was with @property (assign, readwrite) (property type) it was releasing values from attributes

Comment: your welcome. I think that is not the only problem, because from the error log on this like you can see, _reset_code NSString * nil 0x00000000 is nil. which is not being encoded and hence while decoding it's nil. Anyways, it's great that you fixed the issue.